# Using XML::TWIG, how to remove attribute in only one element

Tags: xml, xml-twig

I have an xml looking like this:

```
<first id="1">
 <second id="1">test</second>
 <second>
  <third id="4">test</third>
 </second>
 <second id="3">test</second>
</first>
```

and I would like to remove the "id" attribute but only in the "first" element. Using XML::TWIG, i did this:

```
$twig->parsefile('test.xml');
my ($model) = $twig->first_elt('first[@id]');
$model->strip_att('id');
```

The problem is, it removes the "id" attributes in all the element, not just "first", so the final file looks like this:

```
<first>
 <second>test</second>
 <second>
  <third>test</third>
 </second>
 <second>test</second>
</first>
```

instead of this:

```
<first>
 <second id="1">test</second>
 <second>
  <third id="4">test</third>
 </second>
 <second id="3">test</second>
</first>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you must use del_att($att) instead of strip_att($att), on documentation you can see this explanation:

```
strip_att ($att) :
```

Remove the attribute $att **from all descendants** of the element   (including the element)

```
del_att ($att):
```

Delete the attribute for the element.

So in your code:

```
$twig->parsefile('test.xml');
my ($model) = $twig->first_elt('first[@id]');
$model->del_att('id');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Works like a charm. It is so simple, it is a shame I did not find it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't worry it can happen to anyone :).